# What does it take for field in an entity to be able to be used in cotexetual filter, or relationship?

Tags: views

I am using a view for an entity.  I had it working until I changed the cardinality of a taxonomy field.  Now that field is no longer available for relationships, or contextual filters.  Every other field defined is available as a contextual filter.

So this makes me wonder what determines whether a field can be used in a contextual filter?

Answer (score 0):

Since you changed the cardinality to more than 1.

Add a contextual filter of Has Taxonomy Term ID, then scroll all the way down, click on the blue MORE button and checkmark allow multiple values.

[image]

Yeah, it's hidden, lol.

Comment: Thats, my problem.   Changing the cardinality does removes  "Has Taxonomy Term ID" from my list of filters

Comment: thats odd, it shouldn't do that, didn't to me.

Comment: try testing on fresh drupal install

Comment: or try chaging the cardinality back to 1, save ur view with the contextual filter, then change card back to >1. Coz I did it like that.